# centos 7.4: uname -r not showing full kernel version

Tags: centos, rhel

```
$ cat /etc/system-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 

$ uname -r
3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64
```

and I've installed `sudo yum install kernel-devel` and I see kernel module installed

```
$ ls /lib/modules
3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
```

i have an open-source Makefile i am trying to build which invokes `uname -r`

```
Makefile:KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

I am getting a "No such file" error because `uname -r` is not displaying full version ie `3.10.0-693.21.1`; it's only displaying `3.10.0-693`

--
I've tried this on a RHEL7.2 VM and `uname -r` is showing full version

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64
```

I am not sure if this is a centos vs rhel7 thing?

How can I get centos `uname -r` to show `3.10.0-693.21.1`?

Comment: I'm on CentOS 7.3.1611 and I get `3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64` as the output, and there's a `/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64/` directory as well. Are you on a VPS? Have you rebooted since last updating the kernel?

Comment: @muru hi muru what do you mean VPS. I am running centos in a container. and yum installing kernel-devel happens at docker build stage

Comment: If you're running CentOS in a container then `uname -r` will reflect the host's kernel version.

Comment: oh yes, you are right docker host is showing the same uname -r